# Unity Graphical Editor is broken

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-editor

[image: link]

The white part sometimes grabs onto colors underneath, and I can't click on anything but the toolbars, where all the subwindows also have the same problem

[image: same problem]

I have suspicions that it is a problem with my NVidia GeForce, but I've tried going as far as uninstalling unity, manually deleting everything unity related and reinstalling and the glitch still exists.

Answer (score 0):

That seems like a problem caused by old DirectX.

I had the same problem with 2018, and I fixed it on Win7 by installing the KB2670838 update. However, I can see you're using Win10, so this specific upgrade isn't available to you.

To be sure that it's not a problem of Unity, try launching it with the following command line arguments: `-force -glcore` and see if you have the same glitch when using OpenGL.

If not, I suggest you try to update the nVidia drivers to the latest version, and check if you have the latest version of DX12 on your OS.

If the problem persists, I suggest you contact directly someone at Unity.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the screen size. My screen was blown up by 25% change it in the display settings.